# How to split a column containing strings with comma into multiple columns, then drop the original column in Python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe with columns containing strings with comma. I want to split these columns into multiple columns and drop the original column.

An example of the data is given below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City, Country': ['Thimphu, Bhutan', 'NY, USA', 'London, UK'],
                   'Currency, POP':['BTN, 1.0', 'USD, 20.0', 'GBP, 12.0']})
```

I want to wrangle it to give output as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Thimphu', 'NY', 'London'], 'Country': ['Bhutan', 'USA', 'UK'], 'Currency': ['BTN', 'USD', 'GBP'], 'POP': ['1.0', '20.0', '12.0']})
```

As I do not want to 'manually' split, rename and drop each column, I have defined a function to do the work.

```
def splitDropCols(col_name, df):
    new_col_names = col_name.split(',')
    new_col_names = [x.strip() for x in new_col_names]
    df[new_col_names] = df[col_name].str.split(',', expand = True)
    df.drop(columns = col_name, inplace = True)
    return df
```

However, it is giving `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine for the sample. Could it be that there's an item in a column that you want to split that has more than one `,`?

Comment: Bingo. Thank you for comment. I found that the last column of my real data has more than one comma. Therefore, I have modified my code to limit the no. of splits.  The issue is resolve now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- split values by `', '` separator and explode them into separate rows with `df.explode`
- split all columns by `', '` separator and collect pairwised values for each separate column

---

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(', ')).explode(df.columns.tolist())
df = pd.DataFrame(dict((col, df[c].values[i::2]) for c in df.columns
                       for i, col in enumerate(c.split(', '))))
print(df)
```

---

```
      City Country Currency   POP
0  Thimphu  Bhutan      BTN   1.0
1       NY     USA      USD  20.0
2   London      UK      GBP  12.0
```

Comment: Can you explain your code especially how you are building the df using dictionary comprehension. I am unable to understand it. My original issue, though, is caused due to having more than one delim ',' in the data.

Comment: @UgyenNorbu, the logic fits to your expected output and assumed that column name and column values have 2-word substrings with `,` as delimiter. **`i`** in  `for i, col in enumerate(c.split(', '))` points to a column's ordinal position, and `df[c].values[i::2])` extracts the values from the original "merged" column according to aforementioned column position - it would be even or odd (`0` and `1` consecutively)